# Problem generating manifest in VB.NET 2005

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005

I am using source safe to maintaine my code.
Recently I copied my code to another machine.

But everytime i build my project i am getting below error:

Problem generating manifest. Could not load file or assembly 'D:\WorkingFolder\Project\SubFolder\obj\Release\SubFolder.exe.manifest' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

When i check above manifest file is empty (0k).

I tried rebuilding (after cleaning solution) , also tried with copy pasting previus manifest file content.

None of above solution worked.How to solve this problem?

OS       : XP
Database : Sybase

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. I had created an instance of a timer with

```
Private MyTimer as New Timer
```

I removed the `New` keyword, making it

```
Private MyTimer as Timer
```

and the error went away.

I have no idea what the basis of the problem is, but that's how I solved it.